# Jquery UI - Draggable and Sortable inside the Container/ Parent Div

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

[image]

While dragging a `<div>` for sorting, if I drag the any box outside of container it comes outside of container `<div>`. I don't want this.

I except the output is while Sorting, the dragging (ex. above green background div) `<div>` should not comes outside of parent/Container DIV.

[Demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/ezhil/z9qzw5dj/)

```
$(function () {
  $(".drag_wrapper").sortable({
    connectWith: ".drag_wrapper"
  }).disableSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [containment](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment) option:

```
$(function () {
    $(".drag_wrapper").sortable({
        connectWith: ".drag_wrapper",
        containment: ".drag_wrapper"
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: `connectWith: ".drag_wrapper"` doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: It was part of the original sample code, so I left it.